# Prevent puppeteer goto() from failing when timeout occurs for screenshotting

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, aws-lambda, puppeteer, webpage-screenshot

I am using puppeteer core version 19.6.3 through AWS Lambda to take screenshots of webpages. Here's what my code looks like:

```
  // Create a browser instance
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath("./"),
    headless: chromium.headless,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });

  // Create a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set viewport width and height
  await page.setViewport({ width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight, deviceScaleFactor: scaleFactor });
  // Open URL in current page
  await page.goto(websiteURL);

  // Capture screenshot
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes it fails when the page I want to screenshot is heavy and has has lots of iframes. In those cases it fails with `Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`. I don't want to get rid of the timeout completely, because I don't want to this function to take a potentially long time or never end.

Is there some way I can call `page.goto()` and have it wait for the page to load, but if the page doesn't load after 30 seconds (or some other defined timeout), then it just continues on to take a screenshot of the not fully loaded page anyway? I don't care if the resulting screenshot looks bad or incomplete, I still want it to happen no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a try/catch to the `page.goto()` so I could continue to screenshot even if it reached timeout while waiting for loading.

```
  // Open URL in current page
  try {
    await page.goto(websiteURL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error going to page, but continuing with screenshot: ", error);
  }

  // Capture screenshot
  const screenshot = await page.screenshot();
```